# How to download and force the browser to save a file locally in one request?

Tags: java, spring

I have an unusual task. I have to download the file and immediately force my browser to save it locally to disk?

Below, what I have written so far

```
@PostMapping("/uploadFile")
public String uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, Model model) {
    if (file.isEmpty()) {
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("errorMessage", "No file to upload.");
        return "index";
    }
    if(getExtension(file.getOriginalFilename()).equals("XLS") || getExtension(file.getOriginalFilename()).equals("XLSX")) {
        Path copyLocation = Paths
                .get(UPLOAD_DIR + File.separator + StringUtils.cleanPath(file.getName()));
        try {
            Files.copy(file.getInputStream(), copyLocation, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("successMessage", "File upload successfully, uploaded file name: " + file.getOriginalFilename());
    }
    return "response";
}
```

Comment: Hey there, it's not quite clear what you want to do. The code you show here is to upload a file and save it on the disk on the server side. Nothing of that code gets executed in the browser. 

If you want to download a file to the browser, you need some entirely different code. Please also keep in mind you can do NOTHING to force a browser to immediately save it locally to disk. Some browsers will do that, while others will always prompt the user before saving anything.

Comment: I need to upload a file to the server and "return it". As if someone pressing the download button. But in this same request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well great, but you could show what you already have and write exactly what you have a problem with. Can't set the content disposition? Fine, but then you could show what you already have and write exactly what you have a problem with. Can't set the content disposition?

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Resource> handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=dupa.xlsx").body(file.getResource());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning String (view in this case I assume) you can change your endpoint to return byte array with the file content

```
public @ResponseBody byte[] uploadFile(
```

You should also provide configuration to the @PostMapping with the media type of the file if you know what kind it's going to be.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/uploadFile", produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
```

Another solution is to return ResponseEntity. The documentation has two examples for it (https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Successfully returned the file using IOUtlils, but I have a problem with MediaType. Because I'm returning the xlsx

Comment: You could try with produces = "application/vnd.ms-excel;"